# Very slow count in postgresql with earth_distance and ll_to_earth

Tags: postgresql, gis

I have a very small table "events" with just **10,703** records.
The following query takes about **600 ms**:

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM events 
WHERE event_date > now() 
    AND earth_distance((select position from zips where zip='94121'), ll_to_earth(venue_lat, venue_lon))<16090;
```

I tried to set gis index like this

```
 CREATE INDEX latlon_idx on events USING gist(ll_to_earth(venue_lat, venue_lon));
```

but it didn't change anything. I also have index on event_date.
Here's explain analyze:

```
Aggregate  (cost=5400.48..5400.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=615.479..615.479 rows=1 loops=1)    InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Scan using zips_zip_idx on zips  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=0.051..0.056 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: ((zip)::text = '94121'::text)    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events  (cost=144.41..5386.03 rows=2468 width=8) (actual time=16.065..599.613 rows=3347 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (event_date > now())
         Filter: (sec_to_gc(cube_distance(($0)::cube, (ll_to_earth((venue_lat)::double precision, (venue_lon)::double precision))::cube)) < 16090::double precision)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_date_idx  (cost=0.00..143.79 rows=7405 width=0) (actual time=13.523..13.523 rows=7614 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (event_date > now())  Total runtime: 615.663 ms (10 rows)
```

What else I can try to speed it up?

Comment: Was able to reduce it down to 80ms by adding earth_coord field and precomputing ll_to_earth for every row. I wonder if there's a better way or anything else I can do.

Comment: Test with an index on "event_date"?

Comment: @bma yeah, I have an index on event_date

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I didn't see it in the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output. Do you have a bloated table? If you can afford a short period of time where other transactions against the table are blocked, try issuing `CLUSTER events USING events_date_idx`. The CLUSTER command will remove bloat and rewrite your table in the order of the referenced index. After the cluster, run `ANALYZE events`.